# Override standard tab name in detail page

Tags: apex, visualforce, button-overrides

I have a Tab - say "Issue Tracker". On clicking this, a vf page is opened from which 3 options(links) can be selected. On selecting any of the links, user is directed to the standard new page layout like 'New Issue Tracker'. I need to override this name - Issue Tracker on the detail page based on the link that was selected. e.g if the user selected 'Defects' as the first link, the new page layout should be "New Defect" 7 so on.

Comment: Hi 
I just need one clarification, the name which you want to override is standard text field name right

Comment: HI - The name is the  tab name. I wish to override that. Thus here is the scenario: Click on Tab - 'Issue Tracker'; a new vf page opens up with three links in it -1] Defects 2] Backlogs, 3] xyz. When I click on Defect, the standard page is opened. It looks like - New Issue Tracker. But I need to replace this Issue Tracker name with Defect without renaming the tab.

Comment: It is possible simply by passing value as a url  parameter

Comment: In your case it is very simple as you have intermediate vf page already
here is the example of account object 
[https://ap1.salesforce.com/001/e?acc2=automatic%20account%20name](https://ap1.salesforce.com/001/e?acc2=automatic%20account%20name)

Here acc2 is the account name field
Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much expert but could try on this : 
Per my understanding , I don't think this is possible by any standard means

If you just want to change headings( defect, backlog etc) on Page , Then I think, you can write VF page with standard controller and and pass parameters from the links to decide what should be 'Title' of the pageblock section

If you want to change label of tab itself b, then little extra work is required.

You have to create objects with the names like 'Defect' , 'Backlog' etc. just dummy objects with ono other details. they will be used to control label of Tab

After object creation -  create 3 different VF with standard controller( baed on issue Tracker object) based on parameters passed from links on middle level VF page.

each VF page will have different 'tabstyle' attribute matching names(Defect, backlog etc)  what you want. But inside ,all 3 VF page will still be implementing same standard controller based on Issue tracker object.

Hope this helps!